# Efficient way to filter groups that do not contain all types of elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, grouping

I have a 3 arrays like this:

```
var blues = new int[] {10, 100, 200};
var reds = new int[] {50, 105, 150};
var greens = new int[] {80, 110, 250};
```

Each number indicates a point across a horizontal line.

And if I put everything in one array it will look like this:

```
{ 10, 50, 80, 100, 105, 110, 150, 200, 250}
  b   r   g   b    r    g    r    b    g
              | group 1 |
```

I need to find groups, in which each group has three colors [both blue and red and green], and the distance between the items in the group is not greater than 20 between `blue` and `red`, and not greater than 25 between `red` and `green`.

Is there a known name for such algorithm? And if so what is it?

And what is the best way to implement this algorithm in C#?

The algorithm needs to consider a few things:

1. Can be between 1 and a thousand colors
2. There is an order of colors, and each color must be close enough to the color in front of it according to the maximum distance specified
3. The distance to the preceding color can be positive or negative, unless it is explicitly stated that the distance must be positive
4. Each color has its own unique maximum distance that can be far from the color in front of it
5. The count of points in each color is between 1 and a million, And can be different in each color.
6. Each group must contain all the colors<s>, unless explicitly stated about a particular color that is optional,
   Or it was stated that it is enough to have 40 percent of the colors in the group or 60 percent, etc</s>.

I tried to implement it like this:

```
class ColorPoints
{
    public string Name; // the color name

    public int[] Points;

    public int MaxDistance;

    public bool CanBeNegativeDistance;

    public int[] FinalPoints; // Points that did not fall out of the group
}

public static void GetFinalPoints(ColorPoints[] colorPoints)
{
    if (colorPoints.Length == 1)
    {
        colorPoints[0].FinalPoints = colorPoints[0].Points;
    }

    // ....
}
```

In the above test data the expected result is that 100 105 110 are a good group, and all other points fall out of the group and are disqualified.

An example of using this algorithm could be in a text search.
If the user wants to search for N different words, when between words there is no more than X distance. This is called `W/N operator` - within N words, See [here](https://help.relativity.com/9.6/Content/Relativity/dtSearch/Using_dtSearch_syntax_options.htm#W/N).

[Here](https://github.com/santhoshrajr/ProximitySearch) is a project that deals with the subject, and has an algorithm, but it is only suitable for two colors.

**Here is another example:**

```
var blues = new int[] {10, 20, 100, 200};
var reds = new int[] {50, 105, 150};
var greens = new int[] {80, 110, 250};


{ 10, 20, 50, 80, 100, 105, 110, 150, 200, 250}
  b   b   r   g   b    r    g    r    b    g
                  | group 1 |
```

In this example I added 20 to the blues, it illustrates that each color can have a different number of items.

Another clarification, to create the horizontal line of all the colors together, just take all the numbers from all the colors and sort them, and just remember each number to which color it belongs.
And only after all the numbers are sorted in ascending order, only then do you start looking for groups by distances and other criteria.

Another clarification 2, order within the group does not matter, the colors I mentioned red blue and green this is just an example can be any color in the world also white and any color.

## **EDIT**

Following Konstantin Borisov question I deleted part of the requirement 6.
Now I guess it will be possible to bring an algorithm much faster and better.

**Example of a negative distance:**

```
var blues  = new int[] {10, 105, 200};
var reds   = new int[] {50, 100, 150};
var greens = new int[] {80, 110, 250};


{ 10, 50, 80, 100, 105, 110, 150, 200, 250}
  b   r   g   r    b    g    r    b    g
              | group 1 |
```

In this example, `blue` is first and `red` is second, but the distance between them can be negative, so even though `blue` is at 105 and `red` at 100 they can join one group, then have `green` within 25 of `red`.

Also, in my first example, if we allow a negative distance between `red` and `green` then `80 100 105` would be a valid group.

Comment: Questions like this tends to be quite popular to solve. Can you provide us with expected outcome for your test data?

Comment: @RoarS. The expected result is that 100 105 110 are a good group, and all other points fall out of the group and are disqualified

Comment: Thanks, please add that info to your question in order to get people starting to hack :-)

Comment: A bit confised by your condition `Can be between 1 and a thousand colors` - does it mean you have multiple arrays (i.e. not just RGB), or it's something else?

Comment: @timur Yes, there can be many colors, not just RGB

Comment: it somewhat contradicts your previous statement then: `each group has three colors [both blue and red and green]`. I guess that was an example? How do you specify inputs if you've got more than three arrays?

Comment: @timur See my new edit.

Comment: @googledev Can you say why {100, 105, 80} isn't a valid group? The distance  between red and green is not greater than 25, and you don't mention whether the distance has to be positive. So to be clear, if the distance can be negative, is {100, 105, 80} a valid group?

Comment: @Pluto You said right, if possible a negative distance, this group is valid, and if possible only a positive distance the group is illegal.

Comment: Can you please post how the horizontal line is implemented? perhaps using different number of points per each colour? Thanks

Comment: In the example array layout that you have, what is the significance of the order of placement of the r,g,b components. For eg: you laid out 10, 50, 80 (0th item in b/r/g arrays), 100, 105, 110 (1st item in the b/r/g arrays) in order whereas the third was laid out differently as 150, 200, 250 (r/b/g respectively). If the initial array layout is not constrained, isnt the problem ill-defined. If the initial array layout indeed unconstrained, then couldnt we just pick colors in a sequence that meets your constraint and keep creating valid groups? Please clarify

Comment: with this horizontal line { 10, 20, 50, 80, 100, 105, 110, 150, 200, 250} - this is a valid group {100, 105, 110}. Would this {80, 100, 105} be valid too?

Comment: @AlexLeo Pluto Ask it up.

Comment: When you say find groups, do you want to simply find some groups, find a data structure from which you can find all groups, or find a set of non-intersecting groups?

Comment: @btilly I just want to find groups that meet all the required criteria.

Comment: @googledev My answer gives pseudo-code for how to generate a data structure from which you can produce any or all groups that meet the criteria.

Comment: @googledev does the order of the colours in a group matter? Do they have to be B,R,G? Or it can be different?  If so how it is determined?

Comment: @googledev I really wanted to implement an algorithm for this interesting task but requirements are not clear. You have distance to the previous color. But the distance can be negative. That means that color would be next, not previous. But you allow some numbers to be missing. And it make me completely lost to what color should I calculate distance in this case. It is impossible to solve it this way.
Maybe you want to have a dictionary of distances between pairs of the colors?
And can we have some extra colors in the group? Like brrg?
I think it better to reformulate your question somehow.

Comment: Feels a lot like a 2D matrix transpose.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Please explain.

Comment: nm - my answer was ignorant of the whole problem.  nothing to see here :)

Comment: My idea would be to drop all your values into a flat array, sort them by the number, then scan through the sorted list looking for valid color triplets.  The sort should bring the runtime of the algorithm way down if the values are at all spread out.  Very similar to @KonstantinBorisov 's answer honestly.

Comment: Feels very much like a Google Whiteboard interview question honestly :)

Answer (score 2):

Let me first restate the problem in a more mathematical formulation, while at the same time also slightly generalizing it in a natural way (in the following I use '_' to designate indices; unfortunately SO lacks good support for typing formulas):

Let C_1, ... , C_M be finite subsets of the integers. Let I_2, ... , I_M be integer intervals, i.e. I_j = [a_j, b_j] with a_j <= b_j (all integers). Furthermore, let a real number p in [0, 1] be given.

The task is to find an efficient algorithm to determine the set of groups {G = (c_k_1, ... , c_k_N) | k_1 < ... < k_N are positive integers, c_k_j is an element of C_k_j for all j, c_k_(j+1) - c_k_j is contained in I_(j+1) for all j = 1, ... , N - 1, N >= pM}.

From a mathematical perspective we may assume without loss of generality that p = 1 and hence M=N (as we can solve the problem in turn for all subsets of the color space with N elements and N >= pM).

The algorithm that I propose is very simple: Consider all possible combinations (c_k_1, ... , c_k_M) and test whether they fullfill the desired properties.

Is this algorithm efficient? Certainly there are more efficient algorithms. But the question in practice is not whether we have found the most efficient possible algorithm/implementation (which is hardly ever available), but rather whether it is efficient enough for the given task. Let me add a few further thoughts:

The problem has the unpleasant property that the complexity grows hyperexponentially with the size of the inputs. In the worst case, when the distances are large enough, all combinations are solutions. In the case of 1000 colors with 1 million points each this amounts to (10^6)^1000 = 10^6000 groups. No implementation will ever be able to cope with these numbers (the number of atoms in the universe is estimated to be 10^80). So, every algorithm has its limits with respect to practicable execution (and the limits are pretty small compared to the boundaries given in the question). Given an algorithm, is it worth the effort improving it by, say, a factor of 1000? If you are very lucky, yes, but the odds are against that the the problem you are looking at is exactly in the very small area between the limits of the weaker and the stronger algorithm.

So, my claim is that the naive algorithm proposed above is efficient enough. It definitively is efficient enough to solve the examples in the question in next to no time. My implementation solves the following slight extension of the examples almost instantly:

> The colors:
> Blue:   10, 20, 100, 200
> Red:    50, 105, 150
> Green:  80, 110, 250
> Yellow: 42, 62, 82, 102, 122, 142, 162
>
> The distances:
> From red:    [0,20]
> From green:  [0,25]
> From yellow: [0,25]
>
> 2 colors may be skipped.
>
> The groups:
> B: 100, R: 105
> B: 100, G: 110
> B: 20, Y: 42
> B: 100, Y: 102
> B: 100, Y: 122
> R: 105, G: 110
> R: 50, Y: 62
> R: 105, Y: 122
> R: 150, Y: 162
> G: 80, Y: 82
> G: 80, Y: 102
> G: 110, Y: 122
> B: 100, R: 105, G: 110
> B: 100, R: 105, Y: 122
> B: 100, G: 110, Y: 122
> R: 105, G: 110, Y: 122
> B: 100, R: 105, G: 110, Y: 122

You can find the full implementation at [Arlofin/SO_ColourGroups](https://github.com/Arlofin/SO_ColourGroups). In the following I sketch the essentials.

```
public class Interval
{
    public int LowerBound { get; }
    public int UpperBound { get; }
    // Details elided
}

public class Color
{
    private readonly int[] _points;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<int> Points => _points;

    public Interval Distance { get; }

    public string Name { get; }
    // Details elided
}

public struct ColorPoint
{
    public int Value { get; }
    public Color Color { get; }
    // Details elided
}

public class ProblemSpecification
{
    private readonly Color[] _colors;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Color> Colors => _colors;

    public double Fraction { get; }
    // Details elided
}

public class Group
{
    private readonly ColorPoint[] _elements;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<ColorPoint> Elements => _elements;
    // Details elided
}

public static class SetOperations<T>
{
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> CrossProduct(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sets)
    {
        // Details elided
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T[]> SubSets(IReadOnlyCollection<T> set, int cardinality)
    {
        // Details elided
    }
}

public static class ProblemSolver
{
    private static bool IsGroupValid(Group group)
    {
        return group.Elements.Zip(group.Elements.Skip(1), (pre, el) => el.Color.Distance.Contains(el.Value - pre.Value)).All(b => b);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Group> NaiveSolverFull(IEnumerable<Color> colors)
    {
        var colourPointsPerColor = from color in colors
                                   select color.Points.Select(colorValue => new ColorPoint(colorValue, color));
        var groupCandidates = from colorPointCombination in SetOperations<ColorPoint>.CrossProduct(colourPointsPerColor)
                              select new Group(colorPointCombination);
        return groupCandidates.Where(group => IsGroupValid(group));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Group> NaiveSolver(ProblemSpecification spec)
    {
        int minimalNumberOfColors = (int)Math.Ceiling(spec.Fraction * spec.Colors.Count);
        return Enumerable.Range(minimalNumberOfColors, spec.Colors.Count - minimalNumberOfColors + 1)
            .SelectMany(n => SetOperations<Color>.SubSets(spec.Colors, n)
                .SelectMany(NaiveSolverFull));
    }
}
```

Comment: Groups like: `B: 100, R: 105`, `B: 100, G: 110` invalid because they do not contain all the colors.

Comment: Sure, that's how I configured it as item 6 in your question allows for colors to be skipped (see the output: "2 colors may be skipped"). Just change the parameter p to 1 and the solution produces only groups with all 4 colors.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not called a fast algorithm, this code does not use binary search or any method to improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is additional information about the negative distance processing the algorithm is completeley reworked for using recursion.

Some notes:

- It is pretty fast in terms of grows with the points number. The time complexity is limited by sortig (which is pretty fast, O(ln*log n));
- The distance can affect performance significantly. If you have distance which covers the whole array then you will need to check all the points combinations. And this can't be helped. Hope it's not the case and the groups are somewhat compact.;
- I added 1M random RGB colors and it worked 30s on my desktop;

```
class Program
{
    class ColorPoints
    {
        public string Name; // the color name
        public int[] Points;
        public int MaxDistance;
        public bool CanBeNegativeDistance;
    }

    class IndexesRange
    {
        public int indexMin { get; set; }
        public int indexMax { get; set; }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    class GroupFinder
    {
        public List<Item[]> groups { get; set; } = new List<Item[]>();
        Item[] array;
        List<ColorPoints> colors;
        public GroupFinder()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            var blues = /*Enumerable.Range(0, 333333).Select(s => rnd.Next(1000000)).ToArray();*/new int[] { 10, 20, 100, 200 };
            var reds = /*Enumerable.Range(0, 333333).Select(s => rnd.Next(1000000)).ToArray();*/ new int[] { 50, 105, 150/*,76,82*/ };
            var greens = /*Enumerable.Range(0, 333333).Select(s => rnd.Next(1000000)).ToArray();*/ new int[] { 80, 110, 250/*,79,81*/ };
            colors = new List<ColorPoints>();
            colors.Add(new ColorPoints() { Name = "Blue", Points = blues });
            colors.Add(new ColorPoints() { Name = "Red", Points = reds, MaxDistance = 20, CanBeNegativeDistance = true });
            colors.Add(new ColorPoints() { Name = "Green", Points = greens, MaxDistance = 25, CanBeNegativeDistance = true });
            // Transform input in a one-array form
            array = colors.SelectMany(sm => sm.Points.Select(s => new Item() { Color = sm.Name, Number = s })).OrderBy(o => o.Number).ToArray();
            //Console.WriteLine("{0}", string.Join(",", array.Select(s => s.Color[0]+s.Number.ToString())));
        }
        public void FindGroups()
        {
            var index = 0;
            while (index < array.Length)
            {
                if (array[index].Color == colors[0].Name) // Finde the firtst color
                {
                    var curColor = 0;
                    IndexesRange range = GetIndexesRange(index, curColor);
                    for (var i = range.indexMin; i <= range.indexMax; i++)
                    {
                        ProcessColor(curColor + 1, i, new List<Item>() { array[index] });
                    }
                }
                index++;
            }
            
        }

        public void ProcessColor(int curColor, int index, List<Item> currentGroup)
        {
            if (array[index].Color == colors[curColor].Name)
            {
                currentGroup.Add(array[index]);
                if (curColor < colors.Count - 1)
                {
                    IndexesRange range = GetIndexesRange(index, curColor);
                    for (var i = range.indexMin; i <= range.indexMax; i++)
                    {
                        ProcessColor(curColor + 1, i, currentGroup);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    groups.Add(currentGroup.ToArray());
                    currentGroup.RemoveAt(colors.Count - 1); // Remove the last color since we are moving backward now
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the possible indexes for the next color.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index">Current index.</param>
        /// <param name="curColor">Current color index.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IndexesRange GetIndexesRange(int index, int curColor)
        {
            var range = new IndexesRange();
            // Search for the left side of the indexes range
            range.indexMin = index;
            var nextColor = colors[curColor + 1];
            if (nextColor.CanBeNegativeDistance) // The next color might be bofore this one
            {
                while (range.indexMin > 0 && array[index].Number - array[range.indexMin].Number <= nextColor.MaxDistance)
                {
                    range.indexMin--;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                range.indexMin++;
            }
            range.indexMin++; // We found an element which is already doesn't fit and we need the leftest possible

            // Search for the right side of the indexes range
            range.indexMax = index;

            while (range.indexMax < array.Length && array[range.indexMax].Number - array[index].Number <= nextColor.MaxDistance)
            {
                range.indexMax++;
            }
            range.indexMax--; // We found an element which is already doesn't fit and we need the rightest possible

            return range;
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var groupFinder = new GroupFinder();
        groupFinder.FindGroups();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000);
        foreach (var group in groupFinder.groups)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", group.Select(s => $"{s.Color}{s.Number}")));
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with negative distance, thank you.

Comment: If you sorted your `Item array` by the `Number`, your group search would go much faster as once your distance is out of range, you no longer need to continue the inner length loop.  As the values are all integers, I am betting a linear time type sort might be usable as well.  Also, this is a double nested loop as written so it appears to be O(n^2) complexity, not linear.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan The inner loop is by colors which are limited by 1000. O(1000*n)=O(n)
We have sorting on top on that which is O (n*log(n)) and it is more than the find algorithm itself. So temporary complexity now is determined by the sorting.

Comment: @googledev Based on your latest updates about the negative distances I completely rewrited the solution. Please check.

Comment: Sorting of integers + a few color states need not be n log(n).  Burn a bit of RAM and you can get that linear.

Comment: This has an exponential complexity (due to recursion in `ProcessColor`). It has to, because there can be exponentially many groups. Even with two colors: black and white, with whites having all odd numbers 1,3,5,...999999 and blacks having all even numbers 2,4,6,...1000000, with MaxDistance set to 1000000, there can be ~0.25 * 10^12 groups. And just to display or even create these groups, you need time proportional to the number of groups times the length of each group (number of colors). This is more than n log n.

Comment: @ciamej You calculation is correct for the case when MaxDistance cover all the array (basically depends on 'n'). This is what my second note is about. If the MaxDistance is fixed is small, which I really hope the case, the result will be different.

Comment: Well, it basically does not change radically, if you consider that each point connects to only a handful of other points of the next color. Let's say each point connects to 10 other points. Then, you'll have to execute more than `10^m` where `m` is the number of colors. It all works well only when you consider a constant number of colors (as you do). But that is a really bold assumption to treat the number of colors as constant. Why treat the number of colors as constant and the number of points variable? Why not the other way?

Comment: You've tested with 1 million RGB points. If you'd tested with 5 colors it would take much longer than 30s. If you'd tested with 1000 colors, it wouldn't probably finish before the heat death of the universe.

Comment: @ciamej Then why do you use single variable Big O notation if there are several variables? We need to use Big O for multiple variables then http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~rhowell/asymptotic.pdf 
I showed dependency on the number of points only, that's why the other variables are constants.

And as you might noticed I do not argue with you. You point was one of my initial points. I do not deny it. Increasing of colors and/or distance will have dramatic results.

Comment: Sure, just wanted to point this stuff out, because I thought that the beginning of your answer is overly optimistic ;) especially the complexity analysis could use some disclaimer, like "for a constant number of colors"

Comment: I also wonder how did you perform the random test, i.e. how did you generate the data, what was the range and distance used?

Comment: @ciamej Understand :) But at first the task was just unresolvable and I spend a couple of rounds just to clarify requirements. Currently the task really is exponential, before it was more close to factorial.  I just gave the author a tool with which he can explore his task and see what restriction he might put to narrow down the search. So my optimism was just to encourage the author play with that code and move forward.
I used the data: 3 colors, distances 25 and 20, can be negative. Ranges were generated like this: Enumerable.Range(0, 333333).Select(s => rnd.Next(1000000)).ToArray();

Answer (score 1):

Provided 2 approaches. First approach is simply Brute Force using recursion. Second approach uses some graph theory and implements a Depth-First search algorithm.

Edit: Added a 'sliding window' to the brute force approach to skip some unnecessary iterations.
Edit2: Created second Graphed approach using a Depth-First search algorithm.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Color_Finder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //int[] blues = new int[] { 10, 105, 200 };
            //int[] reds = new int[] { 50, 100, 150 };
            //int[] greens = new int[] { 80, 110, 250 };
            //int[] yellows = new int[] { 0, 10, 101 };
            bool IsNegativeDistance = true;

            ////FindGroup finder = new FindGroup_Windowed();
            //FindGroup finder = new FindGroup_Linked();

            //finder.AddColor("Blue  ", 20, IsNegativeDistance, blues);
            //finder.AddColor("Red   ", 25, IsNegativeDistance, reds);
            //finder.AddColor("Green ", 10, IsNegativeDistance, greens);
            //finder.AddColor("Yellow",  0, IsNegativeDistance, yellows);

            FindGroup finder1 = new FindGroup_Windowed();
            FindGroup finder2 = new FindGroup_Linked();

            Random r = new Random();
            int numColors = 6;
            int numPoints = 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < numColors; i++)
            {
                List<int> list = new List<int>();
                for (int j = 0; j < numPoints; j++)
                {
                    list.Add(r.Next(0, numPoints * 10)); //for ints
                }
                int maxDist = r.Next(1, 300);
                finder1.AddColor($"Color{i.ToString()}", maxDist, IsNegativeDistance, list.ToArray());
                finder2.AddColor($"Color{i.ToString()}", maxDist, IsNegativeDistance, list.ToArray());
            }

            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            finder1.GetColorGroups();
            Console.WriteLine($"Window Time: {DateTime.Now - start}");

            DateTime start2 = DateTime.Now;
            finder2.GetColorGroups();
            Console.WriteLine($"Links  Time: {DateTime.Now - start2}");

            finder1.Print();
            finder2.Print();

            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public interface FindGroup
        {
            void AddColor(string Name, int MaxDistanceToNext, bool IsNegativeDistance, int[] Points);
            List<List<int>> GetColorGroups();
            void Print();
        }


        //Brute Force approach. Not very elegant, but it works
        public class FindGroup_Windowed : FindGroup
        {
            public FindGroup_Windowed(bool IsVerbose = false)
            {
                Colors = new List<Color>();
                this.IsVerbose = IsVerbose;
            }

            private List<Color> Colors { get; set; }
            private List<List<int>> Groups { get; set; }
            private int NumSteps { get; set; }
            private bool IsVerbose { get; }

            public void AddColor(string Name, int MaxDistanceToNext, bool IsNegativeDistance, int[] Points)
            {
                Colors.Add(new Color(Name, MaxDistanceToNext, IsNegativeDistance, Points));
            }

            public List<List<int>> GetColorGroups()
            {
                NumSteps = 0;
                Groups = FindColorGroups(0);
                return Groups;
            }

            public void Print()
            {
                if (IsVerbose)
                {
                    Console.Write("Colors:\n");
                    for (int i = 0; i < Colors?.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"Name={Colors[i].Name}, MaxDist={Colors[i].MaxDistanceToNext}, Points=[{string.Join(", ", Colors[i].Points)}]\n");
                    }
                    Console.Write("\n");

                    Console.Write("Groups:\n");
                    for (int i = 0; i < Groups?.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Groups[i].Count; j++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(Groups[i][j].ToString());
                            if (j < Groups[i].Count - 1) Console.Write(", ");
                            else Console.Write("\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.Write($"Window: Num Steps taken: {NumSteps}\n");
                Console.Write($"Window: Num Groups Found: {Groups.Count}\n");
            }


            private List<List<int>> FindColorGroups(int colorIndex)
            {
                if (Colors.Count <= colorIndex) return null;

                Color current = Colors[colorIndex];
                List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();

                int lowerBoundIndex = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < current.Points.Length; i++)
                {
                    int pointA = current.Points[i];

                    List<int> group = new List<int>();
                    group.Add(pointA);
                    List<List<int>> nextPoints = FindNextColor(colorIndex + 1, group, ref lowerBoundIndex);
                    if (nextPoints != null) ret.AddRange(nextPoints);
                }
                if (IsVerbose) Console.Write("\n");

                return ret;
            }

            private List<List<int>> FindNextColor(int colorIndex, List<int> group, ref int lowerBoundIndex)
            {
                if (Colors.Count <= colorIndex) return null; // found end of complete group :)

                List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
                Color prev = Colors[colorIndex - 1];
                Color current = Colors[colorIndex];
                int pointA = group.Last();
                int nextLowerBoundIndex = 0;

                for (int i = lowerBoundIndex; i < current.Points.Length; i++)
                {
                    NumSteps++;
                    int pointB = current.Points[i];
                    int dist = pointB - pointA;
                    if (IsVerbose) Console.WriteLine($"{colorIndex - 1}: {pointA}, {pointB} = {dist}");

                    int minDist = prev.IsNegativeDistance ? -prev.MaxDistanceToNext : 0;
                    //points are in ascending order
                    if (dist < minDist)
                    {
                        lowerBoundIndex = i; //set lower end of window. this will slide forward as the prev Color iterates through its points.
                    }
                    else if (minDist <= dist && dist <= prev.MaxDistanceToNext)
                    {
                        List<int> newGroup = new List<int>(group);
                        newGroup.Add(pointB);
                        List<List<int>> nextPoints = FindNextColor(colorIndex + 1, newGroup, ref nextLowerBoundIndex);
                        if (nextPoints != null) ret.AddRange(nextPoints);
                        else ret.Add(newGroup); // found end of complete group :)
                    }
                    else //if (prev.MaxDistanceToNext < dist)
                    {
                        break; //all points past this are going to be to far away too.
                    }
                }

                return ret;
            }

            private class Color
            {
                public Color(Color color)
                {
                    this.Name = color.Name;
                    this.MaxDistanceToNext = color.MaxDistanceToNext;
                    this.IsNegativeDistance = color.IsNegativeDistance;
                    this.Points = color.Points;
                }
                public Color(string Name, int MaxDistanceToNext, bool IsNegativeDistance, int[] Points)
                {
                    Array.Sort(Points);

                    this.Name = Name;
                    this.MaxDistanceToNext = MaxDistanceToNext;
                    this.IsNegativeDistance = IsNegativeDistance;
                    this.Points = Points;
                }

                public string Name { get; }
                public int MaxDistanceToNext { get; }
                public bool IsNegativeDistance { get; }
                public int[] Points { get; }
            }

        }


        public class FindGroup_Linked : FindGroup
        {
            public FindGroup_Linked(bool IsVerbose = false)
            {
                this.Colors = new List<ColorLinked>();
                this.IsVerbose = IsVerbose;
            }

            private List<ColorLinked> Colors { get; set; }
            private List<List<int>> Groups { get; set; }
            private int NumSteps { get; set; }
            private bool IsVerbose { get; }

            public void AddColor(string Name, int MaxDistanceToNext, bool IsNegativeDistance, int[] Points)
            {
                Colors.Add(new ColorLinked(Name, MaxDistanceToNext, IsNegativeDistance, Points));
            }

            public List<List<int>> GetColorGroups()
            {
                NumSteps = 0;

                //Build links between colors
                BuildLinks();

                //iterate through links
                Groups = FindColorGroups();

                return Groups;
            }

            public void Print()
            {
                if (IsVerbose)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Colors:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < Colors?.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name={Colors[i].Name}, MaxDist={Colors[i].MaxDistanceToNext}, Points=[{string.Join(", ", Colors[i]._points)}]");
                        for (int j = 0; j < Colors[i].Points?.Count; j++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Value={Colors[i].Points[j].Value}, Next=[{string.Join(", ", Colors[i].Points[j].Next.Select(x => x.Value))}]");
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("");

                    Console.WriteLine("Groups:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < Groups?.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < Groups[i].Count; j++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(Groups[i][j].ToString());
                            if (j < Groups[i].Count - 1) Console.Write(", ");
                            else Console.Write("\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Links: Num Steps taken: {NumSteps}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Links: Num Groups Found: {Groups.Count}");
            }


            private void BuildLinks()
            {
                ColorLinked current;
                ColorLinked next;
                int lowerBoundIndex = 0;

                for (int colorIndex = 0; colorIndex < Colors.Count - 1; colorIndex++) //minus 1 because last color has nowhere to go
                {
                    current = Colors[colorIndex];
                    next = Colors[colorIndex + 1];
                    lowerBoundIndex = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < current.Points.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Point pointA = current.Points[i];

                        for (int j = lowerBoundIndex; j < next.Points.Count; j++)
                        {
                            NumSteps++;
                            Point pointB = next.Points[j];
                            int dist = pointB.Value - pointA.Value;
                            if (IsVerbose) Console.WriteLine($"{colorIndex}: {pointA.Value}, {pointB.Value} = {dist}");

                            int minDist = current.IsNegativeDistance ? -current.MaxDistanceToNext : 0;
                            //points are in ascending order
                            if (dist < minDist)
                            {
                                lowerBoundIndex = j; //set lower end of window. this will slide forward as the prev Color iterates through its points.
                            }
                            else if (minDist <= dist && dist <= current.MaxDistanceToNext)
                            {
                                pointA.Next.Add(pointB);
                                pointB.Prev.Add(pointA);
                            }
                            else //if (prev.MaxDistanceToNext < dist)
                            {
                                break; //all points past this are going to be too far away too.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (IsVerbose) Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            private List<List<int>> FindColorGroups()
            {
                List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();

                foreach (Point point in Colors[0].Points)
                {
                    List<int> path = new List<int>();
                    path.Add(point.Value);
                    List<List<int>> groups = helper(point, path);
                    if (groups != null) ret.AddRange(groups);
                }

                return ret;
            }

            private List<List<int>> helper (Point point, List<int> path)
            {
                if (point.Next.Count == 0) return null; // found end of grouping
                List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();

                foreach (Point next in point.Next)
                {
                    //NumSteps++;
                    List<int> nextPath = new List<int>(path);
                    nextPath.Add(next.Value);
                    List<List<int>> nextGroup = helper(next, nextPath);
                    if (nextGroup != null) ret.AddRange(nextGroup);
                    else if(nextPath.Count == Colors.Count) ret.Add(nextPath); // found end of complete group :)
                }

                return ret;
            }

            private class ColorLinked
            {
                public ColorLinked(string Name, int MaxDistanceToNext, bool IsNegativeDistance, int[] Points)
                {
                    Array.Sort(Points);

                    this.Name = Name;
                    this.MaxDistanceToNext = MaxDistanceToNext;
                    this.IsNegativeDistance = IsNegativeDistance;
                    this._points = Points;
                    this.Points = new List<Point>();

                    foreach (var value in Points)
                    {
                        this.Points.Add(new Point(value));
                    }
                }

                public string Name { get; }
                public int MaxDistanceToNext { get; }
                public bool IsNegativeDistance { get; }
                public int[] _points { get; }
                public List<Point> Points { get; }
            }

            public class Point
            {
                public Point(int value)
                {
                    this.Prev = new List<Point>();
                    this.Next = new List<Point>();
                    this.Value = value;
                }

                public List<Point> Prev { get; set; }
                public List<Point> Next { get; set; }
                public int Value { get; set; }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution utilizing <s>binary search</s> precomputed lower bounds. I've based the code on [Vargo's brute force](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63711111/821497).

Additionally, as a precomputing phase through backtracking I remove all the points which cannot be part of a complete group. This is necessary to avoid dead ends. Thus, when there are only a few possible groups the algorithm does not explore exponentially many possible groups.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Color_Finder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] blues = new int[] { 10, 105, 200 };
            int[] reds = new int[] { 50, 100, 150 };
            int[] greens = new int[] { 80, 110, 250 };
            bool AbsoluteDistance = true;

            FindGroup finder = new FindGroup_BruteForce();
            finder.AddColor(new Color("Blue  ", 20, AbsoluteDistance, blues));
            finder.AddColor(new Color("Red   ", 25, AbsoluteDistance, reds));
            finder.AddColor(new Color("Green ", 10, AbsoluteDistance, greens));

            List<List<int>> groups = finder.GetColorGroups();

            finder.Print();

            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public interface FindGroup
        {
            void AddColor(Color newColor);
            List<List<int>> GetColorGroups();
            void Print();
        }

        public class FindGroup_BruteForce : FindGroup
        {
            public FindGroup_BruteForce()
            {
                Colors = new List<Color>();
            }

            private List<Color> Colors { get; set; }
            private List<List<int>> Groups { get; set; }

            private int[][] LowerBounds;

            public void AddColor(Color newColor)
            {
                Colors.Add(newColor);
            }

            public List<List<int>> GetColorGroups()
            {
                Groups = FindColorGroups();
                return Groups;
            }

            public void Print()
            {
                Console.Write("Colors:\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < Colors?.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"Name={Colors[i].Name}, MaxDist={Colors[i].MaxDistanceToNext}, Points=[{string.Join(", ", Colors[i].Points)}]\n");
                }
                Console.Write("\n");

                Console.Write("Groups:\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < Groups?.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Groups[i].Count; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(Groups[i][j].ToString());
                        if (j < Groups[i].Count - 1) Console.Write(", ");
                        else Console.Write("\n");
                    }
                }
            }

            private bool InRange(bool AbsoluteDistance, int MaxDist, int p1, int p2)
            {
                return (AbsoluteDistance && p1 - p2 <= MaxDist && p2 - p1 <= MaxDist)
                        || (p1 <= p2 && p2 - p1 <= MaxDist);
            }

            private bool ExistsInRange(int[] Points, bool AbsoluteDistance, int MaxDist, int p)
            {
                int lower = AbsoluteDistance ? p - MaxDist : p;
                int upper = p + MaxDist;
                int lowerIdx = Array.BinarySearch(Points, lower);
                if (lowerIdx < 0) lowerIdx = ~lowerIdx;

                return lowerIdx < Points.Length && Points[lowerIdx] <= upper;
            }

            private List<List<int>> FindColorGroups()
            {
                // Eliminate points that do not connect to any point in the next color
                for (int i = Colors.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    Color c = Colors[i];
                    Color d = Colors[i + 1];
                    c.Points = Array.FindAll(c.Points, p1 => 
                      ExistsInRange(d.Points, c.AbsoluteDistance, c.MaxDistanceToNext, p1));
                }

                LowerBounds = new int[Colors.Count - 1][];

                for (int i = 0; i < Colors.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    Color c = Colors[i];
                    Color d = Colors[i + 1];
                    LowerBounds[i] = new int[c.Points.Length];
                    int k = 0;

                    for (int j = 0; j < c.Points.Length && k < d.Points.Length; j++) 
                    {
                        while (k < d.Points.Length && !InRange(c.AbsoluteDistance, 
                                  c.MaxDistanceToNext, 
                                  c.Points[j], 
                                  d.Points[k]))
                            k++;
                        LowerBounds[i][j] = k;
                    }
                }

                Color current = Colors[0];
                List<List<int>> ret = new List<List<int>>();
                List<int> group = new List<int>(Colors.Count);

                for (int i = 0; i < Colors.Count; i++)
                    group.Add(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < current.Points.Length; i++)
                {
                    int pointA = current.Points[i];

                    group[0] = pointA;
                    FindNextColor(1, i, group, ret);
                }
                Console.Write("\n");

                return ret;
            }

            private void FindNextColor(int colorIndex, int pointIndex, List<int> group, List<List<int>> ret) 
            {
                if (Colors.Count <= colorIndex) // found end of complete group :)
                {
                    ret.Add(new List<int>(group));
                    return;
                }

                Color prev = Colors[colorIndex - 1];
                Color current = Colors[colorIndex];
                int pointA = group[colorIndex - 1];

                // int lower = prev.AbsoluteDistance ? pointA - prev.MaxDistanceToNext : pointA;
                // int upper = pointA + prev.MaxDistanceToNext;
                // int lowerIdx = Array.BinarySearch(current.Points, lower);
                // if (lowerIdx < 0) lowerIdx = ~lowerIdx;
                // int upperIdx = Array.BinarySearch(current.Points, upper);
                // if (upperIdx < 0) upperIdx = ~upperIdx - 1;
                int lowerIdx = LowerBounds[colorIndex - 1][pointIndex];
                for (int i = lowerIdx; i < current.Points.Length; i++)
                {
                    int pointB = current.Points[i];

                    if (!InRange(prev.AbsoluteDistance, prev.MaxDistanceToNext, pointA, pointB))
                        break;

                    int dist = pointB - pointA;
                    Console.WriteLine($"{colorIndex - 1}: {pointA}, {pointB} = {dist}");
                    
                    group[colorIndex] = pointB;
                    FindNextColor(colorIndex + 1, i, group, ret);
                }
            }
        }


        public class Color
        {
            public Color(string Name, int MaxDistanceToNext, bool AbsoluteDistance, int[] Points)
            {
                Array.Sort(Points);

                this.Name = Name;
                this.MaxDistanceToNext = MaxDistanceToNext;
                this.AbsoluteDistance = AbsoluteDistance;
                this.Points = Points;
            }

            public string Name { get; }
            public int MaxDistanceToNext { get; }
            public bool AbsoluteDistance { get; }
            public int[] Points { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

The above code has worst-case complexity of `O(NM + NG) = O(N * (M + G))`, where `N` is the number of colors, `M` is the maximum number of points of a given color, and `G` is the number of groups that can be found given the constraints. The `O(NM)` is for precomputing, and `O(NG)` for the actual algorithm. I believe this to be optimal.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a C# programmer.

But if you want to find all such groups, your `FinalPoints` should be replaced with something that looks like more this:

```
class PointOptions
{
    public int Point;
    public int[] PreviousPointIndexes;
}
class ColorPoints
{
    public string Name; // the color name
    public int[] Points;
    public int MaxDistance;
    public bool CanBeNegativeDistance;
    public PointOptions[] FinalPointsWithOptions;
}
```

And now you initialize the first `FinalPointsWithOptions` with every point of the first color, and an empty `PointOptionIndexes`.

Then for each color in turn, you go through its points, doing a scan of the previous color's `FinalPointsWithOptions` to find for each point, which previous options can be options for this one.  That logic looks something like this pseudocode:

```
Lower = 0
for Point in ThisColor.Points:
    while PrevColor.PointOptionIndexes[Lower].Point is too small:
        Lower++
        if Lower = PrevColor.PointOptionIndexes.length:
            break
    if Lower = PrevColor.PointOptionIndexes.length:
        break
    i = Lower
    Options = []
    while PrevColor.PointOptionIndexes[i].Point exists and is not too large:
        options.append(i)
    if 0 < options.length:
        ThisColor.PointOptionIndexes.append(PointOptions(Point, Options))
```

And now the `PointOptionIndexes` starting from the last color works like a linked list going backwards, with every path backwards giving you yet another group.

Now you're in a position to count them, return them, generate them all, or randomly sample them.  (There can be many groups.)

Comment: Thanks, I have a hard time understanding the answer, and I also can not check if it works, please write a code that can be compiled, in C++ or Python.